# How do I check if a string is a valid md5 or sha1 checksum string

Tags: java, md5, sha1, checksum

I don't want to calculate a file's checksum, just to know if a given string is a valid checksum

Answer (score 65, accepted):

SHA1 verifier:

```
public boolean isValidSHA1(String s) {
    return s.matches("^[a-fA-F0-9]{40}$");
}
```

MD5 verifier:

```
public boolean isValidMD5(String s) {
    return s.matches("^[a-fA-F0-9]{32}$");
}
```

Comment: The regexp in the answer validates strings with string length greater than 40 chars, this should fix it: `^[a-fA-F0-9]{40}$`

Comment: Obviously this is old, but the two regexes should be anchored to the beginning and end of the string, per the above comment...

Comment: This does **not** indicate the hash used, it just shows that the hash output is compatible in size with the hash algorith, and only **IF** it is encoded in hexadecimals (which is somewhat standardized, but base 64 would also be a good encoding). It won't detect the type of algorithm either as it could be, say, RIPEMD160 instead of SHA-1. It won't detect if any spaces or separator characters are used either. So beware; I'd at least indicate clearly what the function does in the documentation.

Answer (score 16):

Any 160-bit sequence is a possible SHA1 hash. Any 128-bit sequence is a possible MD5 hash.

If you're looking at the hex string representations of them, then a sha1 will look like 40 hexadecimal digits, and an md5 will look like 32 hexadecimal digits.

Comment: so check for a 40 digit and 32 digit hex number respectively

Comment: This answer is better because it explains why.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as an MD5 or SHA-1 string, at least not one that is standardized. All you can test for is the size of the byte array: 16 for MD5 (a hash with an output size of 128 bits) or 20 bytes for SHA-1 (a hash with an output size of 160 bits) encoded using hexadecimal encoding or base 64 encoding.

If you use `md5sum` then generally the checksum is shown as hexadecimal encoding, using *only* lowercase characters (followed by the file name or `-` for standard input). Hexadecimals are generally preferred, but hashes may also contain separator character or use a different encoding such as base 64 or base 64 URL (etc. etc.).

The byte size you are testing for might however belong to an entirely different hash such as [RIPEMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RIPEMD) that may also have the same output size. Or it may be another value with the same amount of bytes.

Answer (score -1):

MD5 verifier:

```
public boolean isValidMD5(String s) {
return s.matches("[a-fA-F0-9]{32}");}
```

And remove "-" of the string value.

Answer (score -1):

**RegExp SHA-1**

```
public static final String SHA_1 = "^([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:]){19}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})$";

public boolean isValidSHA1(String s) {
    return s.matches(SHA_1);
}

boolean isValidSHA1 = isValidSHA1("12:45:54:3A:99:24:52:EA...");
```