# How to check if input string is a hash of algorhitms from list: ["md5", "sha1", "sha256"]

Tags: java, cryptography, md5, sha1, sha256

I have to write method like this:

```
boolean isHash(String str){
  ...
}
```

Method should return true if input string is `md5` hash or `sha1` hash or `sha256` hash.

Is it possible to implement such method ?

Comment: Possible Duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/a/1896748/11640763

Comment: Each hash has varying lengths and standards. What have you tried?

Comment: @stud3nt, what about sha256?

Comment: @stud3nt is it the only hash algorythms which matches such regex?

Comment: No, different hash algorithms will output different length hashes. If you just want to check if a given string is valid hash or not, you can just check with the character length based on which hash algorithm is used.

Comment: See you can not reverse a hash. So even if i type in gibberish 32 length characters `ar1c2asasabcasdkjasdhj21jkasda12`, it could be a valid md5 hash of a string.

Answer (score 3):

You can validate the hash by checking hex string representations in it using regex or any other way in java.

For example (if we have a string - "test"):

**md5** hash = 098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6 
 Regex - `^[a-fA-F0-9]{32}$`

**sha1** hash = a94a8fe5ccb19ba61c4c0873d391e987982fbbd3 
 Regex - `^[a-fA-F0-9]{40}$`

**sha256** hash = 9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08 
 Regex - `^[a-fA-F0-9]{64}$`

Comment: Note that there are other algorithms, even standardized ones such as SHA3-256 and the lesser known SHA-512/256 that have the same output size as SHA-256 hash. Basically you confirm that the input consists of a specific number of hex encoded bytes, nothing more, nothing less. And yes, the output sizes of the algorithms in the question differ.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Agree, it will be easy to differentiate between md5, sha1 and sha256 hashes because they are all of different output sizes.

Comment: invalid answer as you gave the regex but, didn't specify what method to use. I had to search on three other forums to see it was String#matches